# Filetype associations in Linux

Tags: linux, file-types

I'm curious how file association management is implemented in Linux. Where is the related information stored? How do I modify it (*I'm interested in non-KDE-based ways; I know there's a system configuration page for that in KDE*)?

Links to corresponding articles/documentation will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most desktop environments use Freedesktop.org [**MIME Actions spec**](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/mime-actions-spec). Every program has a **`.desktop` file** in `/usr/share/applications` and/or `~/.local/share/applications`, providing information about the program and the MIME types it accepts. User's own preferences are kept in `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`.

URI schemes, such as `http:` or `mailto:`, are simply listed as special `x-scheme-handler/scheme` MIME types. (Older programs may still be using GNOME- or KDE-specific URI scheme databases, though.)

---

Some "traditional" mail programs, such as Alpine or Mutt, still use the older `~/.mailcap` file for determining the best tool to view attachments with. This is partially because they are purely terminal-based, and require different mechanisms.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the manual (and the actual shell script) for `xdg-open`. It does check if you are using KDE, Gnome, lxde, and passes the file on to `kde-open` and so on. If you aren't running any of those, it looks them up using `xdg-mime`. 
You can look up information on how this work at [freedesktop](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/shared-mime-info-spec).